# how to apply Form validators on object

Tags: forms, scala, validation, playframework, play-json

I have an API in Scala. When I want to create a new User, i need validators on some fields (UserName, FirstName, LastName). I can't find a solution to apply the Form on my case class User. I thought using (`User.apply`) this will override automatically my `User` class, but this isn't happening.

**User.scala**

```
 case class User(
              id: Int = 0,
              userName: String,
              firstName: String,
              lastName: String
            )

object User {
  import play.api.libs.json._

  implicit val jsonWrites = Json.writes[User]

  implicit val userReads = Json.reads[User]

  def tupled = (User.apply _).tupled
}

// Form validator for post requests
object UserForm {
  val form: Form[User] = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> number,
      "userName" -> text(minLength = 5),
      "firstName" -> text(minLength = 5),
      "lastName" -> nonEmptyText
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
  )
}
```

**UsersController.scala**

```
def create = Action(parse.json) { implicit request => {
    val userFromJson = Json.fromJson[User](request.body)
    userFromJson match {
      case JsSuccess(user: User, path: JsPath) => {
        var createdUser = Await.result(usersRepository.create(user), Duration.Inf)
        Ok(Json.toJson(createdUser))
      }
      case error @ JsError(_) => {
        println(error)
        InternalServerError(Json.toJson("Can not create user"))
      }
      }
    }
  }
```

**UsersRepository.scala**

```
    def create(user: User): Future[User] = {
      val insertQuery = dbUsers returning dbUsers.map(_.id) into ((x, id) => x.copy(id = id))
      val query = insertQuery += user
      db.run(query)
    }
```

(UsersRepository doesn't matter so much in this problem)

So, when I read the json, I think there need to apply the form validators

```
val userFromJson = Json.fromJson[User](request.body)
```

but nothing happening. Another problem is if I send from client a `null` parameter, will get an error, can not read and create an User.

For example :

`"firstName": ""` - empty userName will pass

`"firstName": null` - will fail

This depends on how is configured the `User` class in client (Angular), with the field null or empty in constructor. I prefer to set it null, even if is a string, if is not a required field (better NULL value in database, than an empty cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a solution, my Form need to be part of object User, and not to be another object.

```
  object User {
  import play.api.libs.json._

  implicit val jsonWrites = Json.writes[User]    
  implicit val userReads = Json.reads[User]

  val form: Form[User] = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> number,
      "userName" -> text(minLength = 2),
      "firstName" -> text(minLength = 4),
      "lastName" -> nonEmptyText
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
  )

  def tupled = (User.apply _).tupled
}
```

and the method in Controller became :

```
def create = Action(parse.json) { implicit request => {
    User.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(Json.toJson("Some form fields are not validated.")),
      success => {
        val userFromJson = Json.fromJson[User](request.body)
        userFromJson match {
          case JsSuccess(user: User, path: JsPath) => {
            val createdUser = Await.result(usersRepository.create(user), Duration.Inf)
            Ok(Json.toJson(createdUser))
          }
          case error@JsError(_) => {
            println(error)
            InternalServerError(Json.toJson("Can not create user"))
          }
        }
      }
    )
   }
  }
```

I know, I need to format my code ... using IntelliJ is so annoying after Visual Studio :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
request.body.validate[User]
```

One other thing, you shouldn't use

```
var createdUser = Await.result(usersRepository.create(user), Duration.Inf)
```

So use val´s over var´s and the other thing, you don't need to force the future to resolve, use it like this:

```
val createdUser = usersRepository.create(user)
createdUser.map(Ok(Json.toJson(_)))
```

And your action should be async.

Comment: Even if I get the result in a new variable (val jsonResult = request.body.validate[User]) the validators are not applied. Looks like User and UserForm are two separated classes. If I do the function async, get another error (type mismatch: found mvc.Result, required: Future[mvc.Result], but my repo already return a Future)

Comment: Yeah if you change to async you need to tweak the code a bit but it is not hard, the other issue just use the reads and writes of play